# Making fireworks

Tags: python, python-turtle

At the end of my loop it should go back and show start and burst the same way it does the first time the program runs.

I have tried moving things around to make it work. I have added a reset and clear to my turtles, and it's not running properly.

```
#import modules
import turtle
import random

#set screen size
win = turtle.Screen()
win.screensize (600,600)

#set turtle for firework
start = turtle.Turtle()
#set turtles for burst
burst1 = turtle.Turtle()

line = random.randint(10, 35)
line2 = random.randint(10, 15)

#background color


#start firework (base)(clear after each step?)


def base():
    for x in range(1):
        start.ht()
        start.up()
        start.goto(random.randint(-100, 100), -300)
        start.down()
        start.setheading(90)
        for x in range(line):
               start.forward(5)
               start.up()
               start.forward(5)
               start.down()
               start.clear()
        start.clear()

#burst
def burst():
    head = 45
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    for x in range(20):
        burst1.ht()
        burst1.up()
        burst1.goto(start.xcor(),start.ycor())
        burst1.down()
        burst1.setheading(head)
        for x in range(line2):
            burst1.forward(5)
            burst1.up()
            burst1.forward(5)
            burst1.down()
            head = head + 15
            turtle.update()
        

#reset
while True:
    base()
    burst()
    start.reset()
    burst1.reset()
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could show an image or explain what you are trying to draw rather than what the code does/doesnt do

Comment: "It's not running properly" is not a particularly clear problem description.

Comment: My apologies I was in a rush at the time of writing this. Essentially I am trying to make a simple firework type explosion. The first time the code runs is what I am going for. A line as if it's firing off from the bottom of the screen to a randomized location above it, and then a pause before it bursts with a firework type explosion.  after the explosion I would like it to restart, going to another random location, shooting up, and then exploding again. I am trying to find an example online to link to.

Comment: found it --- https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=mBJYZiI4&id=0187754CF036EAE3810B1AA0B849FEC6303963AA&thid=OIP.mBJYZiI4A_lZnFN2slJ5vgHaFj&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fcdn.dribbble.com%2fusers%2f213077%2fscreenshots%2f1145547%2ffarwork.gif&cdnurl=https%3a%2f%2fth.bing.com%2fth%2fid%2fR.98125866223803f9599c5376b25279be%3frik%3dqmM5MMb%252bSbigGg%26pid%3dImgRaw%26r%3d0&exph=600&expw=800&q=simple+animated+firework+gif&simid=608024535810538082&FORM=IRPRST&ck=823102798422CBE6F382DB489953FC95&selectedIndex=29&ajaxhist=0&ajaxserp=0

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have it working the way you want, let's fine tune the use of turtle.  This changes the look a bit but is really about proper techniques.  First, don't use `screensize()`, it doesn't do what you want, use `setup()`.

Next, don't use `while True:` in an event-driven environment like turtle.  We can use an `ontimer()` event instead.  This allows up to use `exitonclick()` to end the simulation cleanly by clicking on the window.

Let's avoid clearing the screen, which causes the need for redoing `bgcolor("black")` but instead clear the turtle drawing on the screen.  Since we're using `tracer()`, we can use an addtional `update()` call and we no longer need the `speed()` calls.  Here's the reworked code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint, choice

COLORS = [
    '#FFFFFF', '#FF0000', '#00FF00', '#0000FF', '#FFFF00',
    '#00FFFF', '#FF00FF', '#C0C0C0', '#808080', '#800000',
    '#808000', '#008000', '#800080', '#008080', '#000080',
]

def launch():
    rocket.penup()
    rocket.goto(randint(-100, 100), -300)
    rocket.pendown()

    for _ in range(randint(5, 45)):
        rocket.forward(5)
        rocket.penup()
        rocket.forward(5)
        rocket.pendown()

        screen.update()
        rocket.clear()

def burst():
    angle = 15

    for _ in range(360 // angle):
        firework.penup()
        firework.goto(rocket.position())
        firework.pendown()
        firework.setheading(angle)

        for _ in range(5):
            firework.color(choice(COLORS))
            firework.forward(randint(3, 15))
            firework.penup()
            firework.forward(randint(3, 15))
            firework.pendown()

        angle += 15

    screen.update()

def display():
    firework.clear()
    launch()
    burst()

    screen.ontimer(display, randint(75, 750))

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(600, 600)
screen.bgcolor('black')
screen.tracer(False)

rocket = Turtle()
rocket.hideturtle()
rocket.color('white')
rocket.setheading(90)

firework = Turtle()
firework.hideturtle()
firework.pensize(3)

display()

screen.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out! Mostly. Sorry for the terribly worded first post.

```
#import modules
import turtle
import random
import time
#set screen size
win = turtle.Screen()
win.screensize (600,600)

#set turtle for firework
start = turtle.Turtle()
#set turtles for burst
burst1 = turtle.Turtle()

burst1.ht()
colors = ["#FFFFFF","#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF","#FFFF00","#00FFFF","#FF00FF","#C0C0C0","#808080","#800000","#808000","#008000","#800080","#008080","#000080"]

#background color


#start firework (base)(clear after each step?)


def base():
    for x in range(1):
        start.ht()
        start.pencolor("White")
        start.speed(0)
        start.up()
        start.goto(random.randint(-100,100),-300)
        start.down()
        start.setheading(90)
        for x in range(random.randint(5, 45)):
               start.forward(5)
               start.up()
               start.forward(5)
               start.down()
               start.clear()

#burst
def burst():
    head = 15
    burst1.speed(0)
    burst1.pensize(3)
    for x in range(25):
        turtle.tracer(0,0)
        burst1.ht()
        burst1.up()
        burst1.goto(start.xcor(),start.ycor())
        burst1.down()
        burst1.setheading(head)
        for x in range(5):
            burst1.color(random.choice(colors))
            burst1.forward(random.randint(3, 15))
            burst1.up()
            burst1.forward(random.randint(3, 15))
            burst1.down()
            head = head + 15
            turtle.update()
        

#reset
while True:
    win.bgcolor("black")
    base()
    burst()
    turtle.clearscreen()
```

Answer (score 0):

@cdlane - here is what I came up with last night after figuring out what I posted before hand. I am going to use some of your advice/example to clean up my code. Thanks so much for the help/knowledge! Feel free to run this and let me know what you think.

```
#import modules
import turtle
import random
import time
#set screen size
win = turtle.Screen()
win.screensize (600,600)

#set turtle for firework
start = turtle.Turtle()
#set turtles for burst
burst1 = turtle.Turtle()
burst2 = turtle.Turtle()
build = turtle.Turtle()

burst1.ht()
colors = ["#FF0000","#00FF00","#0000FF","#FFFF00","#00FFFF","#FF00FF","#C0C0C0","#808080","#800000","#808000","#008000","#800080","#008080","#000080"]

#background color


#start firework (base)(clear after each step?)

def building():
    build.ht()
    build.pencolor("white")
    build.speed(10)
    build.up()
    build.goto(-350,-300)
    build.down()
    build.setheading(0)
    build.forward(10)
    for x in range(10):
        build.setheading(90)
        build1 = random.randint(10,50)
        build.forward(build1)
        build.setheading(0)
        build.forward(random.randint(10,20))
        build.setheading(270)
        build.forward(build1)
        build.setheading(0)
        build.forward(random.randint(1,20))
    build.pencolor("black")
    build.forward(25)
    build.pencolor("white")
    build.forward(10)
    for x in range(10):
        build.setheading(90)
        build1 = random.randint(10,50)
        build.forward(build1)
        build.setheading(0)
        build.forward(random.randint(10,20))
        build.setheading(270)
        build.forward(build1)
        build.setheading(0)
        build.forward(random.randint(1,20))
    


def base():
    for x in range(1):
        start.ht()
        start.pencolor("White")
        start.pensize(1)
        start.speed(0)
        start.up()
        start.goto(random.randint(-300,300),-300)
        start.down()
        start.setheading(90)
        for x in range(random.randint(5, 45)):
               start.forward(5)
               start.up()
               start.forward(5)
               start.down()
               start.clear()

#burst
def burst():
    head = 15
    burst1.speed(0)
    burst1.pensize(2)
    for x in range(25):
        turtle.tracer(10,0)
        burst1.ht()
        burst1.up()
        burst1.goto(start.xcor(),start.ycor())
        burst1.down()
        burst1.setheading(head)
        for x in range(5):
            burst1.color(random.choice(colors))
            burst1.forward(random.randint(3, 15))
            burst1.up()
            burst1.forward(random.randint(3, 15))
            burst1.down()
            head = head + 15
            turtle.update()

def small_burst():
    head = 15
    burst2.speed(0)
    burst2.pensize(1)
    for x in range(25):
        turtle.tracer(10,0)
        burst2.ht()
        burst2.up()
        burst2.goto(start.xcor(),start.ycor())
        burst2.down()
        burst2.setheading(head)
        for x in range(5):
            burst2.color(random.choice(colors))
            burst2.forward(random.randint(2, 5))
            burst2.up()
            burst2.forward(random.randint(2, 10))
            burst2.down()
            head = head + 15
            turtle.update()
        

#reset
while True:
    win.bgcolor("black")
    building()
    base()
    burst()
    base()
    small_burst()
    base()
    small_burst()
    turtle.clearscreen()
```